# bash echo not displaying values

Tags: bash, input, echo, sh

When I run the following script, echo does not display anything and I don't know why. It works if I just type it into the terminal, but not from the shell script. Need some insight please. I might be tired but I'm very certain this should work:

```
#!/bin/sh
for n in `seq 1 10`
do
   r=$RANDOM
   t=$RANDOM
   s=$RANDOM
   f=$RANDOM
   echo "$r $t $s $f"
done
   echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your terminal probably runs a different shell than `/bin/sh`. For example, on Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` runs `/bin/dash`, but `$RANDOM` does not work there. You have to run `/bin/bash` or `/bin/ksh` to make it work.

Comment: my shell works fine, like I said:

**It works if I just type it into the terminal**



Oh nvm, thanks for that guys. I was running the script with the command: **sh ./run.sh** instead of **bash ./run.sh**

Comment: @Smac89: **Than put the correct path to your terminal's shell to the first line of the script.**

Answer (score 1):

When run from a terminal, you probably use bash, not sh.

Seems sh doesn't support `$RANDOM` and thus all variables you assign in your script will be assigned the empty string. Try changing the  first line of your script to `#!/bin/bash` (or whereever bash is installed).